# style.backgroundColor is an empty string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, properties

I have the following code below that I'm trying to set a background color. However, the background color returns as an empty string. I'm not sure why...Does it have something to do with javascript types?

```
function function1(){
var color = document.getElementById('rg_vw.national_avg').style.backgroundColor;
//this below appears as an empty alert at runtime. it's an empty string. 
alert(color)
}
```

Just as a sanity check, if I use the 'value' property, it prints out the correct value for that particular field...so I'm just a bit frustrated as to why the backgroundColor is an empty string.

```
//this works just fine
var value = document.getElementById('rg_vw.national_avg').value
alert(value)
```

Comment: How exactly are you setting the background color?

Comment: Java!=JavaScript  Please read the helpful descriptions of tags before slapping them on questions!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unless you have directly defined the backgroundColor on the element itself, you have to use `getComputedStyle()` or `currentStyle` to get the value of a style property.

A method that is compatible with multiple browsers would look like this:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        return el.currentStyle[styleProp];

    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)[styleProp];
}
```

You can see a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p65N/).

More information:

- See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) for more information about `getComputedStyle()`.
- See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about `currentStyle` (IE).
- See [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) for more information about browser compatibility issues.

Comment: You can use `window.getComputedStyle` directly. 
In the link you shared says: 



"In many code samples, getComputedStyle is used from the document.defaultView object. In nearly all cases, this is needless, as getComputedStyle exists on the window object as well. It's likely the defaultView pattern was a combination of folks not wanting to write a testing spec for window and making an API that was also usable in Java."

Answer (score 1):

Very short

```
const style = document.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('node_identifier'))
```

Then you can get the css property by this

style.width for width; style.background for background