# A small issue with the color background onclick

Tags: javascript

My goal: Change the color of a balloon each time I click on it. 
My problem: The console log show me that my color is empty the first time instead to get the data from css the balloon will be blue and not green. Do you know why ? Do you have any tips for solve this ?

```js
function change() {
  var balloon = document.getElementById("balloon");
  var color = balloon.style.backgroundColor;
  if (color == "red")
    color = "green";
  else
    color = "blue";
  balloon.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50%;
}

#balloon {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="balloon" onclick="change();"></div>
```

Comment: `style` will try to get the style that is defined in the `style` tag, not the one in the class the element is using.

Comment: You want to use `getComputedStyle`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: toggle a class and save yourself the troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `style` attribute for checking the element's `background-color` proprety, but instead you should use `window.getComputedStyle()` method to check for the CSS rules that are applied to the element, so you have to change a little bit your code.

change() function:

```
function change() {
  var balloon = document.getElementById("balloon");
  var color = window.getComputedStyle(balloon, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
  if (color == "red")
    color = "green";
  else
    color = "blue";
  balloon.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

The `style` proprety is used for applying style rules, while the `window.getComputedStyle()` method is used for retrieving style rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var element = document.getElementById('balloon'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
Color = style.getPropertyValue('backgroundColor');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call your event handling function you have to use `window.getComputedStyle()` instead of `element.style.backgroundColor`since you defined the `background-color` in a style sheet instead of directly on the element. The code below should do what you're trying to achieve.

[Check out this related SO question for more detail on `window.getComputedStyle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556185/style-backgroundcolor-is-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

```js
var red = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
document.getElementById("balloon").addEventListener('click', change);

function change() {
  var color = this.style.backgroundColor || getComputedStyle(this, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  
  this.style.backgroundColor = getNextColor(color);
}

function getNextColor(currentColor) {
  var color = null;
  
  if (currentColor == "red" || currentColor == red)
    color = "green";
  else if (currentColor == "green")
    color = "blue";
  else
    color = "red"
    
  return color;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*padding-top: 50%;*/
}

#balloon {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="balloon"></div>
```