# Count lines in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a way to count lines in the html so I can do logic for a business requirement.

I use Bootstrap + AngularJS but the solution could be in plain Javascript.

I have no idea where to start. Any help?

```css
.myClass {
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 50px">
  <span class="myClass">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
<span>Total Lines: <b id="totalLines"></b></span>
```

**I also would need a way to calculate this everytime the user makes the window smaller/bigger because of the responsive aspect.**

Comment: Calculate the line height and then divide the total content height by that?

Comment: What is the business requirement? Sounds like an odd request. Maybe there is a better way to solve the underlying issue.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried that but lineHeight gives me empty `""`

Comment: @AndreasHassing basically if the text has more than 5 lines, show the More button to see the rest on the span

Comment: You should add this failed attempt to your question

Comment: Please show how you used the line height?

Comment: ^^ because you're probably running into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556185/style-backgroundcolor-is-an-empty-string-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getClientRects will be useful here

> The getClientRects() method of the Element interface returns a collection of DOMRect objects that indicate the bounding rectangles for each CSS border box in a client.

```js
$("#totalLines").text($(".myClass")[0].getClientRects().length);
console.log($(".myClass")[0].getClientRects().length);

$(document).ready(function() { 
                $(window).resize(function() { 
                console.log("Resize event fired");
                   $("#totalLines").text($(".myClass")[0].getClientRects().length);
                }); 
            });
```

```css
.myClass {
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="max-width: 500px">
  <span class="myClass">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
</div>
<span>Total Lines: <b id="totalLines"></b></span>
```

Comment: looks good. But what if the user changes the browser width/height. How can I know that and recalculate?

Comment: @user12361681 You have to use it in `resize` event of window.